# How to place buttons in both the center and the right of a Linear Layout

Tags: android-layout

My applications looks like this with all the buttons/images centered:
[image]

However, I want it to look like below with the blue icon all the way on the right side:
[image]

I am unable to get the blue icon to the right side no matter what I try. Any advice?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mountain"
    tools:context="com.example.slammy.codechallenge.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/layoutMusicControl"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
    >


        <ImageButton
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_back"
           />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" />


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:background="@drawable/play_active"
                android:tag="play"
               />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnSkip"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_next"
                 />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:background="@drawable/alexaicon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutMusicControl"
             />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show/Hide"
        android:id="@+id/btnShowMusicControls"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `RelativeLayout` it's more appropriate in this case.
You could remove `Space` components with margin.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMusicControl"
    android:background="#000000"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_back"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPlay"
        />


    <ImageButton

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/play_active"
        android:tag="play"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSkip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_next"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:background="@drawable/alexaicon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly. One quick question. The buttons are no longer vertically centered within the relative layout. Do you know the fix to that?

Comment: you could add android:layout_centerVertical="true" on each component